# How to map querystring ?Action=Blah to action in MVC3 route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to use a route with the action in the querystring

http://server/path/controller?action=save

so I can use relative urls on the client-side

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that @Darin provided, is good and useful enough, but there is an issue with `action`s that not supplied by `Html.ActionLink` such as `Index` actions that will cause an error like this:

> The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty
>   string value.

So you have to change the `MyRoute` to this one:

```
public class MyRoute : Route {

    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler()) { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) {

        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        var action = httpContext.Request["action"];
        if (routeData != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(action)) {
            routeData .Values["action"] = action;
        } 

        // you have to add something like this:
        else {      
            routeData .Values["action"] = "Index";
        }
        return routeData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/) which illustrates one technique that would allow you to achieve this. It uses a custom [ActionNameSelectorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameselectorattribute.aspx).

Another possibility if you really want to do this globally would be to write a custom route, like this:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        var action = httpContext.Request["action"];
        if (rd != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
        {
            rd.Values["action"] = action;
        }
        return rd;
    }
}
```

and then register:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(
        "Default", 
        new MyRoute(
            "{controller}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        )
    );
}
```

Now when you request `/home?action=about` it will be the `About` action of the `Home` controller that will get executed. Obviously if you omit the `action` parameter from the request you will get an exception because the `action` token of a route must always be specified or the action invoker wouldn't know which action to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    string action = httpContext.Request.QueryString["Action"];
    routeData.Values["action"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(action) ? "Index" : action;
    return routeData;
}//method
```

but to finish the job you have to implement GetVirtualPath() also:

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) {
    string url = "up to you";
    var data = new VirtualPathData(this, url);
    // also consider DataTokens ...
    return data;
}//method
```

this ensures that helpers such as ActionLink() will generate correct URLs